# Refresh permalink after custom plugin installed and uninstalled

Tags: wordpress

I am making a plugin using `add_rewrite_rule` where need to refresh the permalink after plugin installed and uninstalled. I am stuck with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [flush rewrite rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules).

I used this in my plugin and its working perfectly for me.

Hope this will help you.